# Pdf Flip book in REACT JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flip

Is there any library in react JS which i can use to generate a flip book effect of my PDF? and if there is not any library then how can i achieve my target of creating a flip book from my PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library works fine react-pdf, so you can try too https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of react-pdf (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65447951/3778283)) and then make use of [react-pageflip](https://nodlik.github.io/react-pageflip/) to create the page flip animation, embedding the PDFs within each page.