# Pdf Flip book in REACT

Tags: reactjs, pdf

Is there any library in react JS which I can use to generate a flipbook effect of my PDF? and if there is not any library then how can I achieve my target of creating a flipbook from my PDF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pdf Flip book in REACT JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447935/pdf-flip-book-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service and then embed it with React? Something like [Flipsnack](https://www.flipsnack.com/)